# Receber itens de um feed - Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

Com esse método eu busco todos os itens de uma url. Agora preciso selecionar somente o item da quinta posição, como posso fazer isto e quais alterações devo fazer?

```
private async Task<List<FeedItem>> ParseFeed(string rss)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(rss);
            var id = 0;
            return (from item in xdoc.Descendants("item")
                    let enclosure = item.Element("enclosure")
                    where enclosure != null
                    select new FeedItem
                    {
                        Title = (string)item.Element("title"),
                        Description = (string)item.Element("description"),
                        Link = (string)item.Element("link"),
                        PublishDate = DateTime.Parse((string)item.Element("pubDate")).ToUniversalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
                        Category = (string)item.Element("category"),
                        Mp3Url = (string)enclosure.Attribute("url"),
                        Image = (string)enclosure.Attribute("url"),
                        Color_category =Convert.ToString(int.Parse((string)item.Element("color")), 16).PadLeft(6, '0'),
                    Id = id++
                    }).ToList();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Duas coisas a se observar aqui:

1. Seu método é assíncrono (*async*) então para melhor resultado, você deve esperar o resultado do mesmo através de um operador chamado *await*.
2. Seu método retorna uma lista de *FeedItem* então devemos apenas armazenar esse retorno e buscar a posição pelo índice da lista.

   `// Armazena o feed em uma lista
   List<FeedItem> myFeedList = await ParseFeed("endereço do feed");
   // Busca o quinto elemento da lista, neste caso representado pelo número 5 (coloque a posição que desejar)
   FeedItem feedItem = myFeedList[5];`